# The Overlapping Confusion between the Concepts of Strikes and Lockouts

Tags: unions

Many reputable websites offer the exact same definition of strikes and lockouts. I am not looking for another re-hash of this definition but I will nevertheless state the definition here just for clarity: strikes are employee initiated refusals to work; lockouts are an employer's initiated refusal to give work.

My question however is about the intricate *overlap* between how these two processes (strikes an lockouts) actually work. For example if a union wishes to strike but the employer locks them out, essentially the union is still achieving its end as well -- a stoppage of work. If the employer calls a lock out whose to stop the union from continuing to demand the union's objectives? For example, a lockout is supposed to push a union to accept undesirable demands from the employer, but if the union just refuses the lockout's return to work conditions, how does a lockout benefit an employer? The union can essentially turn the lockout into a strike...and this brings me to the essence of my question. Regardless of who initiates a given stoppage of work, the ball can so easily move to the other player depending on how they play the game. Likewise if a union calls a strike and the employer refuses to alter course, then doesn't it become a lockout?

Again, I am not looking for the same definitional answer which can so easily be found online and which I gave in my first paragraph. I am looking for a real understanding of how these two processes appear oppositional but actually are totally intertwined. And if they are essentially not distinct concepts, then what is the real purpose in separating the concepts into strike and lockout?

Comment: `I am looking for a real understanding of how these two processes appear oppositional but actually are totally intertwined` - The difference is about who initiates the stoppage of work, but the outcome is same - stoppage of work.

Comment: Your examples all seem to assume the union wants a strike. This is a rather artificial restriction when trying to separate two terms differing in *who* wants to stop work. Assume the union does not want to strike and suddenly a lockout - which is not on their terms, which they cannot end, … - is an entirely different thing than a strike.

Comment: A Union could be "working to rule" so the employer does a lockout...

Comment: What jurisdiction? If an employer refuses to give out work in my jurisdiction, they'd still be liable to pay wages, so it wouldn't benefit them at all (its an employer problem if they don't assign work). If a union calls a strike, the union pays strike money which replaces the wages.

Answer (score 4):

A strike shuts down production at the cost of sacrificing wages. A shutdown stops paying wages at the cost of stopping production.

In either case, it's a matter of putting needs and resources against each other until the accumulated pain on both sides forces an agreement.

Yes, a single term ("work stoppage") can be used for both. But mentioning who took it to this level does speed up explaining the current state of negotiations, so we have terms that incorporate that information.

Answer (score 3):

As you say, the difference between a strike and a lockout is whether the workers are boycotting the employer and withdrawing their labour (in the case of strike), or whether the employer is excluding the workers from the workplace and stopping their wages (in the case of lockout).

The terms are not primarily designed to differentiate the practical status of the situation, but differentiate who is controlling the situation.

In the less common situation where both sides think their interests at that very moment are served by a cessation of work and rupture in normal relations, I suspect one or the other term would be chosen arbitrarily, or more abstract language used like an "industrial dispute".

It is of course possible for the situation to evolve freely over time between lockout, strike, or mutual exclusion.

The reason an employer may proceed to a lockout, is because only part of the workforce may be striking and they may be capable of cross-subsidising each other (prolonging their ability to strike), or it may reflect fissures in support amongst the workforce (and by the employer taking industrial action against non-strikers, the assumption may be that they will pressure those in the same local community who are striking).

There are many forms of industrial action workers can take which are beneath an explicit, all-out strike.

Go-slow, sabotage, work-to-rule (malicious compliance), overtime bans, or partial strikes which cause total seizure or large inefficiencies of operations.

There have often been laws in place against withholding wages for work already done (however poorly), as this is both likely to lead to an outbreak of personal violence against the employer or his capital machinery, and (if withholding is allowed at all) most likely to be overused by the employer in a large variety of circumstances so as to almost guarantee the precipitation and suffering of an extreme extra-judicial reaction sooner or later.

You see this today occasionally in cases of so-called self-employment, such as in the building trade where subcontractors use diggers to smash up buildings or cars when payment is withheld.

It is also practically impossible for courts to adjudicate whether a withholding would be deserved, so the practice has long been outlawed to protect employers from violence.

What the employer is practically left with, if he isn't satisfied with the performance of the workforce due to their industrial action lesser than a strike, is the option of a lockout (legally, this is a mass layoff).

In the UK, when the employment of whole workforces could be at-will (before 1963), these lockouts were once a common feature of industrial relations.

Lockouts were thought themselves to ultimately contribute to the solidification and radicalisation of the workforce in the long term, contrary to the interests of employers collectively, and there are now significant controls on how quickly they can occur (and that delay often means the employer would not commonly wish to use the tactic for industrial bargaining).

The equivalent tactic nowadays is to reroute the work to a competitor firm (often owned and controlled by the same banks or capitalist financiers), or to threaten to relocate the operation elsewhere, thus penalising the workforce for challenging the employer in much the same manner as the lockout would.

The outlawing of secondary action (since 1982) also means that the firm to which work is then diverted cannot strike in sympathy.

Comment: In which countries are secondary actions forbidden? I have to assume there's variation in that policy...

Comment: @keshlam, I can only speak definitively for the UK. The law anywhere probably corresponds to trade union strength, since originally all trade union action was unlawful but it was enforced by violence at the grassroots until lawmakers simply accepted the reality of having to bargain collectively with workers. In France for example, I'd be inclined to suspect secondary action is still legal. And I believe it is in Sweden too, having recently heard that Musk and Tesla had fallen foul there.

Comment: I guess I am too much of a right to work/not work individual. And believe that telling me that me deciding to not work is illegal is a form of slavery.

Comment: @Questor, if you're referring to the point about secondary action, it's not so much that the individual cannot take action, but that the individual loses protections that currently exist in law, and the trade union administrations can be penalised for doing anything to encourage it.  Practically speaking, determined wildcat action can still occur if workers are willing to break the law and exert relentless violence, as workers did in the past to establish their rights to strike and collective bargaining, but solidarity is rarely at that level nowadays.